# Is it possible to setup xrebel on google app engine application and how?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, xrebel

I am running a multi module google app engine application. GAE 1.9.50:devserver.
Was wondering how could XRebel be setup

Running server via `mvn appengine:devserver`

Comment: Xrebel is a commercial product. So why are you not using the forum organized by the company selling the product? . Those folks are typically very responsive and helpful.

Comment: Good Point, when was google-ing did not find anything so was hoping to have it documented here in case someone else will need the info on the future.

Comment: Worst case, simply contact their support desk. They can't solve everything, but as said: helpful people there.

Comment: @otc did you find a way to run XRebel with GAE devserver?

Comment: @xybrek I did not, looks like it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, XRebel doesn't integrate with Google App Engine.